# How easily to check: $f$ is a closed map?

Tags: general-topology

Assume that $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a function where $\mathbb R$ is the real number and the usual topology is defined on $\mathbb R$.

I have two questions:
   1. Let $C$ be closed. Then what is the proper form of $C$? For example, without the loss of generality, open set is replaced by the open interval.
   2. To check that $f$ is a closed map, we need some information: $f(C)$ is closed. How to easily check this?

Comment: It will depend on $f$, in general. One can check that $y \in \overline{f[C]}$ implies $y \in f[C]$, e.g., or check that the complement of $f[C]$ is open. Just give us a concrete $f$...

Comment: @henno brandsma Ummm... if f(x)=x^2, then i know that f is closed. How to check this?

Comment: Closed sets do not have a basis in the same way that open sets have a basis, since the arbitrary union of closed sets in not necessarily closed. There is a sense of the dual of a basis for closed sets, since any open set is the union of open intervals, then any closed set is the intersection of the complements of open intervals.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews of course the basic (pun intended) problem is that forward images do preserve unions (so OK for open sets) but not intersections (bad for bad sets). So this representation does not help much.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in the comments, it will depend on the map $f$, in general.

In the case of $f(x) = x^2$ (also see comments) we can write $\mathbb{R}$ as $A \cup B$, where $A = \{x: x \le 0 \}, B = \{ x: x \ge 0\}$, so $A$ and $B$ are closed and $f | A$ and $f|B$ are homeomorphisms onto $[0, \infty)$. If then $C$ is closed, then $f[A \cap C]$ is closed in $[0,\infty)$, as homeomorphisms are closed maps and $A \cap C$ is closed in $A$, and likewise for $f[B \cap C]$. Hence their union which equals $f[C]$ is closed in $[0, \infty)$ as well and thus closed in $\mathbb{R}$ (closed in a closed sets is closed in the whole space). So $f$ is a closed map.

Comment: Wow!! I completely understand! Thanks your help :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to check that a map is closed.

The formula $\overline{f(A)}\subseteq f(\overline A)$ is a description of closed maps. However, since the proof that this formula is equivalent to closedness of $f$ is very easy, I think you could as well show directly that your $f$ is closed.

Here are some hints:

- A characterization of closedness of $f$ is: For each $y\in Y$ and every open $U\supseteq f^{-1}(y)$ there is an open $V\ni y$ with $f^{-1}(V)\subseteq U$.
- Closedness is local in the codomain. This means that for each point $y\in Y$ there is a neighborhood $V$ such that the restricted $f:f^{-1}(V)\to V$ is closed. Equivalently, $Y$ is covered by the interiors of subsets $(V_i)_{i\in I}$, where $f_i:f^{-1}(V_i)\to V_i$ is closed for each $i\in I$. As the restriction $f:S\to f(S)$ of a closed map to a saturated set $S$ is again closed, this condition is also necessary.

The second point can be applied if $f$ is a proper map (preimages of compact sets are compact) and the codomain is locally compact Hausdorff or, more generally, each point in $Y$ has a compact Hausdorff neighborhood. In that case it is easy to prove that $f$ is a closed map. For example, a continuous map from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ is closed if the preimage of a bounded set is bounded, so $f(x)=x^2$ is closed.

Yet another fact: If $f:X\to Y$ is proper and $Y$ is Fréchet-Urysohn and UCC, then $f$ is closed. UCC (*unique convergent clustering*) means that every convergent sequence has a unique cluster point.

Answer (score 0):

To check that $f(C)$ is closed you can either prove that all the limit points of $f(C)$ lie in $f(C)$ or $\mathbb{R}\setminus f(C)$ is open. The second one is easy most of the times but it really depends on what is $f$.
Also open sets are unions of open intervals not only open intervals.

Comment: Ah, I mean if f((a,b)) is open, then the union of f((a,b))'s is also open.